# Save DateTime mysql with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want save in my Datetime field the Date 
For insert i haven't problem...
I have tried many attempts, this is the last but the result is the same

Insert:

```
var now = new Date();
var jsonDate = now.toJSON();
var then = new Date(jsonDate);


var o_voto_foto = {
    profilo_id: profilo,
    foto_id: data.id_foto_votata,
    punteggio: data.voto,
    proprietario_id: data.proprietario_foto,
    created: then
};


connection.query('INSERT INTO prof_voto_foto SET ?', o_voto_foto, function(error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        var err = "Error on INSERT 'votoFotoFancybox': " + error;
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
```

Update table:

```
var now = new Date();
var jsonDate = now.toJSON();
var then = new Date(jsonDate);

connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = ' + data.voto + ', created = ' + then +' WHERE profilo_id = ' + profilo + ' AND foto_id = ' + data.id_foto_votata, function(error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        var err = "Error on UPDATE 'votoFotoFancybox': " + error;
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
```

And i recive this error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Aug 02 2013 19:03:13 GMT+0200 (CEST) WHERE profilo_id = 103 AND foto_id = 5' at line 1
```

Comment: Do not forget to call `connection.escape` on **all** of your values unless you're using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the help of @tadman, it's works

```
created = new Date();
connection.query('UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = ' + connection.escape(data.voto) + ', created = ' + connection.escape(created) + ' WHERE profilo_id = ' + connection.escape(profilo) + ' AND foto_id = ' + connection.escape(data.id_foto_votata), function(error, rows) {
```

Comment: is `connection.escape()` necessary with `Date()` object?

Comment: I agree with @anshabhi you don't need to escape objects that aren't passed in from user input.  the escape is unnecessary here for the date that was created a line above.

Answer (score 16):

Since you are working with current timestamps, you may just consider using the `NOW()` MySQL function instead of populating date from javascript.  Of course, this means you will standardize all timestamps on MySQL server time rather than client's time which may or may not be desirable.

Usage would be like this:

```
'UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = ' + data.voto + ', created = NOW() WHERE profilo_id = ' + profilo + ' AND foto_id = ' + data.id_foto_votata
```

Comment: I prefer this way instead of messing around with JSON dates

Answer (score 5):

The date needs to be enclosed in `"` or `'` so mysql knows it is dealing with a string and can convert it into a datetime.

```
UPDATE prof_voto_foto SET punteggio = ' + data.voto + ', created = "' + then +'" WHERE profilo_id = ' + profilo + ' AND foto_id = ' + data.id_foto_votata
```

And it may need to be formatted to match what mysql is expecting, `Aug 02 2013 19:03:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)` needs to converted to `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`

Answer (score 0):

```
var o_voto_foto = {
    profilo_id: profilo,
    foto_id: data.id_foto_votata,
    punteggio: data.voto,
    proprietario_id: data.proprietario_foto,
    // just delete the stuff you add here :) then add created = now() on the sql statement. that should do the trick
};


connection.query('INSERT INTO prof_voto_foto SET **created = now(),** ?', o_voto_foto, function(error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        var err = "Error on INSERT 'votoFotoFancybox': " + error;
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
```

do the same on the update,